# Best practice to join cluster members without downtime on Neo4j 3

Tags: neo4j

Whenever I want to add a new instance to the cluster I need to configure ha.initial_hosts in all instances and the reboot all of them.
Is there a better way to join a new instance?
Is there a reload configuration option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to just set `ha.initial_hosts` to the list of all existing machines in the cluster + the one to be added on the to-be-added machine and just start it up. It should join the cluster.

You should amend `ha.initial_hosts` on the already running instances with the new instance but there's no need to restart them. As the name infers it's just necessary for initially start up the cluster to reach quorum.